# How do I get the correct context for Python operators?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I am currently trying to use the operator [`bpy.ops.sequencer.duplicate()`](https://pythonapi.upbge.org/bpy.ops.sequencer.html#bpy.ops.sequencer.duplicate) in a python script, but I am having trouble finding the correct context to pass to it, as I am getting the standard `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.sequencer.duplicate.poll() failed, context is incorrect` error.

How do you find what the required context for a Python operator is?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Comment: PS you have a link to an unofficial blender fork's documentation. But here this operator is the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After looking through the api documentation, it does not appear that there is a direct way to know which contexts an operator will work in.
Therefore, one way to determine this is to call an operator's `poll` method in every context to see if the operator will work (brute forcing it). Using this approach, the `bpy.ops.sequencer.duplicate` will work in the `'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'` context, and only the sequence editor.

The script below simply runs through all the areas and polls the operator (line 15).

```
import bpy

#all the area types except 'EMPTY' from blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.type
types = {'VIEW_3D', 'TIMELINE', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'LOGIC_EDITOR', 'PROPERTIES', 'OUTLINER', 'USER_PREFERENCES', 'INFO', 'FILE_BROWSER', 'CONSOLE'}

#save the current area
area = bpy.context.area.type

#try each type
for type in types:
    #set the context
    bpy.context.area.type = type

    #print out context where operator works (change the ops below to check a different operator)
    if bpy.ops.sequencer.duplicate.poll():
        print(type)

#leave the context where it was
bpy.context.area.type = area
```

Comment: Too bad there isn't a lookup or cheat sheet, thanks for the awesome work around!

Comment: This would be a cool addon for the text editor. Add a edit box to type in the operator ... :)