# Is there a way to save all settings of the sequence editor to disk and load them when needed?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

In Python, is there a simple way to save everything in an editor, ex. the `Sequence Editor` to disk and later when needed load everything again?

[image]

The reason for this question is that changing scene will change the contents of most of the editors, and this is not always desired. Being able to save and load all content from from ex. Sequence Editor would be a way to workaround this.

Answer (score 2):

**Sequence Editor belongs to the scene.**

The settings shown are on data that belongs to each scene. A new scene will use blender's defaults.

Python console. Create a sequence editor in the context scene. It is of type [`bpy.types.SequenceEditor`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SequenceEditor.html#sequenceeditor-bpy-struct).  The value for `overlay_frame` is shown

```
>>> sed = C.scene.sequence_editor_create()
>>> type(sed)
<class 'bpy.types.SequenceEditor'>

>>> sed.overlay_frame
0
```

.

To have the same settings in another scene, would suggest creating a new and copying the attributes of the old, or copying the scene and unlinking from it unrequired data, including strips. *Be a good candidate for an operator with presets.*

Alternatively save it as a scene in another blend and  append the scene each time instead of  creating a new one.

Another option would be to save a workspace template or startup file with the settings desired.

Comment: Thank you, but what I'm after is not so much the settings as the full content of the Sequence Editor ex. all of the edited strips. So it's everything nested inside the "Sequence Editor" data structure. So I guess it would have to iterate through all entries, whatever they are and save them to disk in a way they could be loaded back into the sequence again.

Like in the Text Editor where you can load a text-block into the editor and save it too. And even swap between them.

Comment: Envisage something Simalarly to copying nodetree shown here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123887/how-to-copy-nodes-and-their-links-from-one-node-tree-material-to-another-in-py  in conjunction with https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134613/can-python-operator-presets-be-shared-between-operators   _ie_ could generate the sed  preset template via the sed rna properties.

Comment: Maybe that's an idea. To copy all strips to clipboard, save them to disk, and later read them into clipboard and paste that? I wonder what is the most current lib to do that stuff or is there any thing in the included python which lets you read and write from/to the clipboard?

Doing it as in the node example, seems to be codong a full exporter and importer, and that'll be a lot of work. But I guess it could be done with otio: https://github.com/tin2tin/VSE_OTIO_Export

Comment: Stupid me. The copied strips are not stored in the text clipboard... So that approach would need to patch the sourcecode...