# Adding a color effect strip to the video sequencer using Python without the operator?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, color

I'm trying to run this code headless to avoid the context error however I can't find any information about adding a color strip without using `bpy.ops`. How can I convert the following code to not use the operator please?

```
bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add(
    type='COLOR', 
    frame_start=1, 
    frame_end=int(file) * filesCount, 
    channel=1,
    color=(
        backgroundColor['r'] / 255, 
        backgroundColor['g'] / 255, 
        backgroundColor['b'] / 255
    )
)
```

I think it has something to do with [new_effect](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SequencesTopLevel.html#bpy.types.SequencesTopLevel.new_effect) however I can't see an option to add rgb values.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101129/15543

Comment: You beat me to it @batFINGER! Thanks so much! Your solution works perfectly. I really appreciate your help again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@batFINGER to the rescue! The answer to my question can be found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/142392/111345 for anyone else that needs it.

Comment: If so, how about upvoting the answer?

Comment: Just did, thanks for the heads up ;)

Comment: Already did upvote that one too!